# patch: "bad file descriptor" in combination with pipe and LD_PRELOAD/ libtrash

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, dynamic-linking, stdin, patch

**Very short summary:**
`cat "$file" | patch` produces a `Bad file descriptor`-error, but
`patch < "$file"` works, when libtrash is preloaded with `LD_PRELOAD`, and only on bigger projects.

**Description:**
For this example, I work on the vanilla linux-3.18.21 kernel sources as downloaded from [1] (and extracted the archive, of course).

I want to patch it with TuxOnIce as downloaded von [2], and extracted.

In this example I show some big project, since with just small files everything works okay.

I work within the top level linux source directory, and from there the patch is located at `../patches/tuxonice-for-linux-3.18.21-2015-09-08.patch`. No symlinks involved, everything on the same filesystem.

The following happens:

```
$ cat ../patches/tuxonice-for-linux-3.18.21-2015-09-08.patch | patch -p1 --dry-run
patch: **** can't open file Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt : Bad file descriptor
```

(exitcode: 2)

*but*:

```
$ patch -p1 --dry-run < ../patches/tuxonice-for-linux-3.18.21-2015-09-08.patch 
checking file Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt
checking file Documentation/power/tuxonice-internals.txt
[...]
```

(runs successfully).

The problem has something to do with `libtrash.so` loaded via the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable:

- By default, I have `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libtrash.so`. [3]
- If I `export LD_PRELOAD=''` or `unset LD_PRELOAD`, it works fine.
- If I just switch off the functioning of libtrash (but keep it preloaded), by `export TRASH_OFF=YES`, which is the way provided by libtrash, the problems persist.
- It definitely has to do with libtrash and not with `LD_PRELOAD` itself, since when I `export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/lib/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0'` (the file exists) the patching with `cat $file | patch` works.

In fact, I expect `cat "$file" | "$programme"` to result in the same as `"$programme" < "$file"`, but it doesn't.

It's a practical nuisance, since in practice instead of using `cat`, I would use things like `xzcat` or `bzcat` on the compressed patch files so that I don't need to decompress them in an extra step first.

I use `bash`, but that doesn't matter (within `zsh` the same). `patch` is GNU patch version 2.7.5, `glib-config --version` shows 1.2.10, I use an arch linux distribution and this problem did persist already for at least several months, including updates. Kernel 3.18.21.

Here are two outputs with `strace`, once `strace`-ing `cat`, once `strace`-ing `patch`, with `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libtrash.so` and `export TRASH_OFF=YES`:

Command:

```
$ strace cat ../patches/tuxonice-for-linux-3.18.21-2015-09-08.patch | patch -p1 --dry-run
```

Output:

http://pastebin.com/TD81znz6

Command:

```
$ cat ../patches/tuxonice-for-linux-3.18.21-2015-09-08.patch | strace patch -p1 --dry-run
```

Output:

http://pastebin.com/snvN3YCu

(Sorry for linking it, if I would put it directly stackexchange won't accept my post without telling me why).

I am not familiar with dynamic linking, `strace` and so on.

Does anyone know what goes on? If that is a bug somewhere, where would it be? (patch, libc, libtrash, dynamic linker, ..., ..., ?)

`xzcat /usr/src/linux-3.18.21.tar.xz | tar -xv` works (but `xzcat some.patch.xz | patch` does not), so it has at least some specificity with `patch`.

[1] linux kernel: https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.18.21.tar.xz

[2] TuxOnIce: http://tuxonice.nigelcunningham.com.au/downloads/all/tuxonice-for-linux-3.18.21-2015-09-08.patch.bz2

[3] libtrash: http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~marriaga/software/libtrash/

Comment: whats inside `../patches/pf/patch-4.4-pf3`

Comment: Some linux kernel patches, See https://pf.natalenko.name/ (in fact it is the extracted https://pf.natalenko.name/sources/4.4/patch-4.4-pf3.xz). But it does not matter, since this behaviour is also when using other patches. In fact, `cat $file | $programme` _should_ be the same as `$programme < $file`, but it isn't.

Comment: I'd `strace` it to see what it does. There's a couple of things that can be done with a file set to stdin via `<` that can't be done on an input pipe (like reopening or seeking). I guess `patch` is trying to do one of those things.

Comment: I found out that it has to do something with the environment variable `LD_PRELOAD`. I have set it up to provide `libtrash`. When I provide an empty `LD_PRELOAD` to the `cat ... | patch`-command, it still fails, but when I unset it, `patch` works. Though, this is not a satisfying solution yet, since it fails also when I disable libtrash with `TRASH_OFF=YES` but still having the `LD_PRELOAD` set. I don't really understand what is going on -- will provide some more details and add them to my original question.

Comment: Completely rewrote the question.

Comment: Post the output from `cat ../patches/tuxonice-for-linux-3.18.21-2015-09-08.patch | strace patch -p1 --dry-run`  It's the `patch` utility that's having the problem, so you need to provide the `strace` output from `patch` instead of `cat`.  You might also want to send the `strace` output to a file with `strace -o /path/to/output/file ...`.

Comment: @Andrew Henle: I tried, but stackexchange says "Your post could not be edited. Please see the error above." (Or something like that.) It scrolls up to the top. There is no error. When I remove the output, it works. I provided the output in a pastebin.com and linked it in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libtrash` is broken:

For example, in `helpers.c`:

```
char* make_absolute_path_from_dirfd_relpath(int dirfd, const char *arg_pathname)
{
   char *abs_path = NULL;

   if (arg_pathname == NULL)
     {
    return NULL;
     }
   else if (arg_pathname[0] == '/' || dirfd == AT_FDCWD)
     {
    return arg_pathname;
     }
   else if (dirfd <= 0)
     {
    errno = EBADF;
    return NULL;
     }
```

A value of `0` for a file descriptor is perfectly legitimate.  Since you're using redirection, you're reading from `stdin`, which is file descriptor `0`.  I suspect that's what's breaking somewhere in `libtrash`.

Comment: Thanks. Not a C-hacker and not knowing shared library stuff: If I change `if (dirfd <= 0)` to `if (dirfd < 0)`, would that be also OK, or do you expect that it breaks other things?

Comment: I wrote the author of `libtrash`.

Comment: @GolarRamblar - If you make that change, it shouldn't *hurt* anything, but without going through the entire code base there's no way I can guarantee you anything.  I can say that trying to use LD_PRELOAD to successfully interpose on IO calls of any type is extremely difficult to do correctly even when one is completely familiar with how basic Unix-type file descriptors behave.  I encountered numerous bugs in **IBM's** use of LD_PRELOAD interposing when I supported a customer using [IBM SANergy](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg246146.pdf).  And if IBM can't do it without bugs...

Comment: Seems `libtrash` is broken, yes: Recently issues appeared with files getting wrong permissions (`240` instead of `644`, `000`) with `libtrash`: https://github.com/termih/libtrash/issues/3, https://github.com/termih/libtrash/issues/2. Maybe also related with updates in `libc` which `libtrash` is lacking behind?

Comment: @GolarRamblar thank you for having written to me about this. Unfortunately the email didn't make it to my inbox so I only learned about this problem a few weeks ago when I was notified about a *different* problem and a link to this page popped up in Google. :)

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew Henle pointed out, this was due to a bug in libtrash. I have just released [a new version](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~marriaga/software/libtrash/libtrash-latest.tgz) that should fix this behavior.

Comment: "This was a bug, but it's fixed now" seems like a fine answer to me. I moved the other half to a comment